# Auto reconnect to multiple Wi-Fi networks

Tags: windows-10, networking, wireless-networking

I have a PC with two network adapters connected to different Wi-Fi networks. It often drops one of the networks and doesn't attempt to reconnect to it while the other network is still intact. However, if I disable the one connected network adapter in settings, the other one immediately reconnects without issues. So there seems to be no issue in the process of reconnecting itself, but rather in OS' unwillingness to attempt it. Also, it's not always the same network, it can drop one or the other.

How to make Windows automatically reconnect to each network, even when the other one works? Bonus question would be how to troubleshoot second network drops, but just fixing reconnection mechanism would probably be a "good enough" solution.

- OS: Windows 10
- Network adapter #1: D-Link DWA-548 (PCIe), connected to a 2.4 GHz Wi-Fi network
- Network adapter #2: Realtek 8811CU (USB), connected to a 5 GHz Wi-Fi network
- Wi-Fi router: Keenetic Ultra, hosts both Wi-Fi networks simultaneously.

Both networks have good signal on PC - full bars, good speed, low ping, etc. There are about 3-5 other devices on the two networks combined, which is well within router's capabilities, no issues with them. And PC never drops both Wi-Fi networks, one or the other is always kept and works without issues.

Ticked "Connect automatically" checkboxes in Wi-Fi settings for each of the networks for corresponding adapters (one network per adapter). Disabled "Allow to turn off this device to save power" in device manager for both Wi-Fi adapters. I did not bridge connections yet, but might want to do it in the future.

Comment: Are both 2.4GHz and 5GHz networks in the same segment (https://help.keenetic.com/hc/en-us/articles/360005236300-Network-segments)? If yes, they have IP addresses on the same subnet, which is a no-can-do - you can't have two interfaces in the same subnet without applying some kind of link aggregation between the devices.

Comment: @Peregrino69 yes, both networks are in home segment. Not sure what you mean by "you can't have" — when I manually connect PC to both networks, it works fine for a while, and router sees it as two separate devices. Do you mean that router intentionally "fixes" it by dropping one of the adapters? If I have to apply some kind of link aggregation, where can I learn about what exactly I have to do and how?

Comment: Link Aggregation and NIC teaming are too broad subjects to explain here. Wikipedia's article on Link Aggregation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_aggregation (your Keenic doesn't seem to support it). This article in ni.com explains about NIC teaming pretty thoroughly on general level: https://www.ni.com/fi-fi/support/documentation/supplemental/11/best-practices-for-using-multiple-network-interfaces--nics--with.html (including why 2 NICs in one subnet causes connectivity problems). You should google for Win10 specific instructions. What to do and how depends on what you want to achieve.